Snowflake, JSON_EXTRACT_PATH_TEXT select all elements attribute in an array of objects
I have this data in a json column
#mycolumn
{
  "key": "KEY",
  "elements": [
    { "name": "NAME_1" },
    { "name": "NAME_2" }
    { "name": "NAME_3" }
  ]
}

I want to select all the elements[*].name.
I have tried:
select JSON_EXTRACT_PATH_TEXT(mycolumn, 'elements[].name')
select JSON_EXTRACT_PATH_TEXT(mycolumn, 'elements[*].name')
select JSON_EXTRACT_PATH_TEXT(mycolumn, 'elements[0,1,2].name')

Nothing works.
This works:
select JSON_EXTRACT_PATH_TEXT(mycolumn, 'elements[0].name')

But this returns only the first element.name
How can I get all the names?

TRANSFORM can be used SELECT TRANSFORM(mycolumn:elements, x -> x:name) FROM t;. Transform - result

@LukaszSzozda please feel free to add your comment as an answer. I'll accept it. It works

I'll appreciate if someone can explain me why the question is receiving negative votes :/

You need to use LATERAL FLATTEN, like this:
with jdata as (
SELECT try_PARSE_JSON(column1) AS mycolumn
FROM VALUES
('{
  "key": "KEY",
  "elements": [
    { "name": "NAME_1" },
    { "name": "NAME_2" },
    { "name": "NAME_3" }
  ]
}'
)
)
select e.value:name::string
from jdata j, LATERAL FLATTEN(INPUT => mycolumn:elements) e;


Using a higher order function TRANSFORM:
SELECT TRANSFORM(mycolumn:elements, x -> x:name) FROM t;

Output:

